# how to resolve <!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "" }--> in angular?

Tags: angular

I'm using WebApi to return an array of objects. When I'm trying to show the returned data in ngFor loop it gives this comment in elements:""
When I tried showing the static array in ngFor loop it worked but when it's dynamic data it won't work. What should I do?
This is the html:

```
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <th>شماره سریال</th>
            <th>آدرس سایت</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of serialModel">
            <td>{{item.Serial}}</td>
            <td>{{item.RegisterWebsite}}</td>
            <td><qr-code [value]="item.Barcode"></qr-code></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is the method:

```
async OnSearch(Model) {
    this.SearchModel = Model;       
    this.CurrentService.postApiSerialNumberPrintListSerialsResponse(
        Model
    ).subscribe((x) => {
        this.serialModel = x.body;
        console.log("model isssssssssss", this.serialModel);
    });
}
```

This is the log of my returned data:
[image]

Edit:
This is ngInit method where I call onSearch:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.SearchModel = this.sharedService.SearchModel;
     this.OnSearch(this.SearchModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove async in this method OnSearch(Model)

Comment: I did, but I'm still having the same problem

Comment: where do you call method OnSearch(Model)

Comment: on ngInit method. I edited the post

Comment: I think you used onpush detection mode, you can remove it or you can add this.cd.detectChanges(); after this.serialModel = x.body;

Comment: Thank yo so much. it worked. but can you tell me why it was necessary to put that code in my method?

Comment: You are welcome, when using a change detection strategy of OnPush, other than making sure to pass new references every time something should change, you can also make use of the ChangeDetectorRef for complete control. for more information check this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-change-detection-strategy